# present a multi select list as togglebuttons in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm creating a form where the user will select n days from a list of week days.

example - think of a multi select list with the following values: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and the user will select Tuesday and Thursday.

So, on my action I create a select list with the name of the week days and an Id for each of them and pass it to the View inside the ViewData.

```
ViewData["WeekDays"] = new SelectList(weeklist, "Id", "Name");
```

on my Action i have something like this to present the week days:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%  foreach (var day in (SelectList)ViewData["WeekDays"]) {%>
        <a id="<%= day.Value %>" title="<%= day.Text %>" class="toggleOff">
            <%= day.Text %>
        </a>
    <% } %>

    <input type="submit" value="<%= Html.Resource("Continue") %>" />
<% } %>
```

and the page has the following script to create the look and fell of a toggle button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.toggleOff').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("toggleOn");
    });

    $('a.toggleOn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("toggleOff");
    });
}
```

with some css magic for the classes toggleOn and toggleOff this will present a toggle button list to the user.

My problem is how to post back to the controller the days selected by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to found the solution by myself.

On the View I replaced the  tag with two inputs, a button and a hidden input.

```
<%  foreach (SelectListItem day in (SelectList)ViewData["WeekDays"]) {%>
    <input id="SelectedDays_<%= day.Value %>_" name="SelectedDays[<%= day.Value %>]" type="button" value="<%= day.Text %>" class="toggleOff" />
    <input id="SelectedDays_<%= day.Value %>_Hidden" name="SelectedDays[<%= day.Value %>]" type="hidden" value="false" />
<% } %>
```

And used the jquery to set the the hidden input value when someone press the button:

```
$('input.toggleOff').click(function () {
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Hidden';
    $(this).toggleClass("toggleOn");

    if ($(id).attr('value') == "false") {
        $(id).attr('value', 'true');
    } else {
        $(id).attr('value', 'false');
    }
});
```